# How to communicate over LAN in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, windows-7

I am using **GNU GCC compiler(XCODE NOT AVAILABLE)** for running **objective C**.I want to send message from one **HOST** to another over the internal network(Like LAN).I have no Idea how to do it.
Any **BUDDY** to HElp.

Comment: What platform will you be running this client on? iPhone/iOS or Mac OS X?

Comment: On Windows 7,Also,I am using GNU GCC Objective C compiler on Windows 7.I just want make small program in Objective C to send and recieve messages over the LAN.

Comment: Sending/receiving messages over the LAN is not a small program. You need to post the code you have so far so people can help.

Comment: I know it is silly but I don't have any Idea How to even start It,I need help from scratch so I can Proceed... DON'T want Spoon-feeding.

Comment: Looking at all your questions I think that you didn't really understand what this site is about.

Comment: I googled a lot on my problem but didn't find anything that is why I came across the planet of experts.Also May be I couldn't express my problem well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to writing a pain-free client for a platform (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) is using that platform Software Development Kit (SDK).

The SDK will provide tools and platform library to make your development as pain-free as possible.

So your question of asking about compiling Objective-C on Windows sounds like you want to develop a client for Mac OS X or iOS/iPhone platform.  This is no easy task for a person asking on SO how to perform this.  So I would advise against it.